# Converting English to Nepali Typing JS. When I press A it should be translated to ब and so on

Tags: javascript

Converting English Typing to Nepali Typing. When I press A it should be translated to ब and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://www.google.com/inputtools/ to transcribe as you type

A quick google search also proves that similar websites use them
https://www.easynepalityping.com

Answer (score 3):

When I press A it should be translated to ब and so on.

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: https://www.toolsnepal.com/preeti-to-unicode/